# Cannot export kendo grid data to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-grid, llblgenpro

I am exporting data from a Kendo Grid. The code in the controller breaks with a error at the foreach loop.

ERROR MESSAGE

```
  -InvalidCastException-


{"Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType2`6[System.DateTime,System.String,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String]' to type 'ZoomAudits.DAL.TypedViewClasses.ReportPhoneSupportResultRow'."}
```

Stacktrace:

> at
>   UtilityWebSite.Controllers.ReportsController.Export(DataSourceRequest
>   request,  ReportsPhoneSupportSearchVM model) in
>   c:\Users\texas_000\Desktop\UtilityWebSite\UtilityWebSite\Controllers\ReportsController.cs:line
>   130    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.b__3e()

I have searched for possible answers but I am unable to figure out what needs to be changed? The project is setup with LLBL and I am unfamiliar with it. Any help will be great. If you need more information please let me know. thank you

```
public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, ReportsPhoneSupportSearchVM model)
    {
        ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView results = new ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView();
        string[] userIds = model.UserId.Split(',');
        foreach (string userId in userIds)
        {
            int iUserId = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(userId, out iUserId))
            {

                RetrievalProcedures.FetchReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView(results, model.FromDate, model.ToDate, iUserId);
            }
        }

        var Results = from Reslt in results
                       select new 
                      {
                          ActivityDate = Reslt.ActivityDate,
                          Action = Reslt.Action,
                          Assignment = Reslt.Assignment,
                          Description = Reslt.Description,
                          Result = Reslt.Result,
                          ToFrom = Reslt.ToFrom
                      };


        //Get the data representing the current grid state - page, sort and filter
        IEnumerable ExcelResults = Results.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;

        //Create new Excel workbook
        var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        //Create new Excel sheet
        var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet();

        //(Optional) set the width of the columns
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(0, 10 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 50 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(2, 50 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(3, 50 * 256);

        //Create a header row
        var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);

        //Set the column names in the header row
        headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("ActivityDate");
        headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Assignment");
        headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Action");
        headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("ToFrom");
        headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Result");
        headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Description");

        //(Optional) freeze the header row so it is not scrolled
        sheet.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);

        int rowNumber = 1;

        //Populate the sheet with values from the grid data
        foreach (ReportPhoneSupportResultRow ER in ExcelResults)
        {
            //Create a new row
            var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber++);

            //Set values for the cells
            row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(ER.ActivityDate);
            row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(ER.Assignment);
            row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(ER.Action);
            row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(ER.ToFrom);
            row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(ER.Result);
            row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(ER.Description);
        }

        //Write the workbook to a memory stream
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        workbook.Write(output);

        //Return the result to the end user

        return File(output.ToArray(),   //The binary data of the XLS file
            "application/vnd.ms-excel", //MIME type of Excel files
            "GridExcelExport.xls");     //Suggested file name in the "Save as" dialog which will be displayed to the end user

    }
```

Comment: please add the error to your question

Comment: I have it at the top. thanks

Comment: any ideas? do i need to post more information?

Comment: It looks like the type cast conversion is the issue from your result set. Have you debugged the code and inspected the contents of the excelresults object?

Comment: all of the data is there?

Comment: Is it because it is a anonymous type?

Comment: I think you should use a concrete class instead of an anonymous type. Or, use the 'results' variable directly. See http://www.llblgen.com/TinyForum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=22802&StartAtMessage=0&#128981

Comment: I got it, appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. use this code in the FileExport Action

```
ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView results = new ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView();
    string[] userIds = model.UserId.Split(',');
    foreach (string userId in userIds)
    {
        int iUserId = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(userId, out iUserId))
        {

            RetrievalProcedures.FetchReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView(results, model.FromDate, model.ToDate, iUserId);
        }
    }


    //Get the data representing the current grid state - page, sort and filter
    IEnumerable ExcelResults = ((IEnumerable)results).ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
```